# How do I control the notification counter for my home screen app icon?

Tags: ios, notifications

When one first turns on one's iPhone, one is presented with this screen that lists all the apps installed in that phone. Some of them might have little red circles with white numbers in them that represent unread notifications from that app. Now I'm making an iOS app, and I want to trigger the appearance of white numbers in red circles like this. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber:numberDesired];
```

Sets the number currently set as the badge of the app icon in Springboard.

Set to 0 (zero) to hide the badge number. The default value of this property is 0.